# Не до конца понимаю как работают замыкания JS

Tags: javascript

Есть стандартный код

```
function counter(){
    let a=0;
    return function (){
        a++;
        console.log(a);
    }
}
 
count = counter();
count()
count()
count()
```

Если честно не понимаю почему а сохраняет предыдущее значение и таким образом увеличивается каждый раз на 1, а не сбрасывается в 0 при каждом вызове.

Недопонимание начинается здесь

```
count = counter();
```

Здесь сначала выполняется ф-я counter, в ней была объявлена переменная a=0, а возвращаемая анонимная функция попала в переменную count
После того как функция counter выполнилась (в этом месте count = counter() ), она не вылетает из памяти? Ну т.е. после ее запуска, анонимная функция, которую я вызываю через count() теперь постоянно будет видеть переменную "a" внутри counter и при каждом новом вызове соответственно увеличивает предыдущее значение переменной "a" на 1? Так что ли?

Или же анонимная функция не дает выбросить из памяти переменную "a" в функции counter, поскольку это является ее внешним окружением?

Если сформулировать вопрос проще, то я не могу понять, что происходит с кодом функции после ее вызова. Вызвал функцию она выполнилась и вылетела из памяти или вызвал функцию и теперь ее код с этого момента всегда доступен?

Answer (score 2):

Помогла статья фывфывhttps://learn.javascript.ru/closure
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: еще про сборку мусора почитайте :) https://learn.javascript.ru/garbage-collection т.к. формально, не переменной присваивается ф-я, а создается ссылка, которая указывает на объект, который хранится в области памяти. Если ссылка на объект удалена/перезаписана (count=null), то и объект будет удален.

Answer (score 0):

В переменную `count` помещается не только возвращаемое значение, но и объявленные в теле функции переменные. Переменная не удаляется после выполнения функции.

Comment: "Переменная не удаляется после выполнения функции." А не удаляется она потому что внешнее окружение вложенной анонимной функции ссылается на окружение функции "counter". Помогла эта статья https://learn.javascript.ru/closure

Answer (score 0):

А если посмотреть на это в контексте OOП, то примерно это будет так

```
function counter(){ // класс counter 
    let a=0; // поле a в классе counter, инициализированное 0
    return function (){ // метод по умолчанию
        a++;
        console.log(a);
    }
   // собственно методов может быть очень много и один по умолчанию
}
 
count = counter(); // вызов конструктора counter который вернет объект созданный в куче.
count(); // вызов default метода объекта count
```

и сразу жить проще как-то. И то что это объект и создается он в куче и сборщик его почистит когда придет время